# Sparklyr ft_tokenizer err in RLang

Tags: r, sparklyr

I keep getting an error when trying to use ft_tokenizer in sparklyr.
when i execute the following script i keep getting `Error in rlang::env_get(mapping, nm, default = NULL, inherit = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (default = NULL)`

i've already tried downloading the latest version of R studio and have tried with both Microsoft R open and R 3.5.2

```r
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

dataframe  <- data.frame("Review" = "The pictures from online made it seem the room was big", "Review_Is_Positive" = 0 )
write.csv2(dataframe, file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)

dataframe.spark <- spark_read_csv(sc, 
                                  name =  "test",
                                  "test.csv",
                                  overwrite = TRUE,
                                  delimiter = ";")

dataframe.spark

dataframe.spark <- ft_tokenizer(dataframe.spark, input_col = "Review", output_col = "tokens")
spark_disconnect(sc)
```

Anyone out there that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try update rlang from development version:

```
devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang")
```